# Can you pay for a RyanAir flight by wire transfer?

Tags: tickets, ryanair, payment

I would like to buy Ryanair tickets and I would like my company to pay for it by wire transfer. Ryanair doesn't offer this on their website, they only accept credit/debit card payments.

I am wondering if there are any travel agencies where I can order ryanair tickets online and pay the agency by wire transfer? Any recommendations?

Comment: A local TA might do this for you but it would be no different to the company wiring the money to you after you pay for the flight on a personal card. Can I ask why you would like your company to pay this way? It seems unnecessarily complicated compared to using a company card or claiming as an expense.

Comment: I know you can with Wizz Air if you can find a flight with them, another budget European airline. just use your order number as a reference within 24hours of booking, done it recently for a flight to Lithuania. Not putting this as the answer as you might only want to use RyanAir

Answer (score 2):

> **How can I pay for my flights?    There’s loads of ways to pay for your
>   Ryanair flights.**
>
> We accept PayPal, American Express cards, Visa, Mastercard, Apple Visa
>   and Apple Mastercard credit cards and the following debit cards Visa
>   Connect, Visa Electron, Mastercard Prepaid, Visa Delta.
>
> Payments made by Apple Visa and Apple Mastercard will only be accepted
>   on our mobile app at present. For customers in Germany ONLY, SEPA
>   direct debit payments can be accepted up to 10 days prior to the
>   flight departure.
>
> Bookings paid for by PayPal, American Express, credit cards or a
>   Mastercard Prepaid card will incur a fee of 2% of the total
>   transaction value.
>
> No credit card fee applies when paying with a debit card or SEPA bank
>   transfer (Germany only).

https://www.ryanair.com/gb/en/useful-info/help-centre/faq-overview/Making-payment#0-2